# clear date-picker when it is wrapped in a custom component

Tags: angular

I Know most of the people are familiar with dp-date-picker. for some reason I need to wrap it inside a component that I made it myself and its name is bh-date-picker. the problem is I cannot clear this date picker and the interesting issue is that the clear works for the first time only!
I have used NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR for better usage of this component but for some reason I dont know why I cannot clear it

I have designed a link for you which has one datepicker and one clear button 
you can see that it just works for the first time only.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3gpkhy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by a trick
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t9mrgs

```
this.ref.dateModel='';
this.ref.dp.inputElement='';
this.ref.dp.inputElementValue='';
this.ref.dp.inputElementContainer.children[0].attributes[2].nodeValue='';
this.ref.dp.inputElementContainer.children[0].attributes[2].textContent='';
this.ref.dp.inputElementContainer.children[0].attributes[2].value='';
this.ref._dateModel='';


this.ref.dp.api.open();
this.ref.dp.api.close();
```

here as you can see opening and closing the datepicker can solve the problem I dont know its the best solution or not but it solved my problem